# calculate data transfer download+uploaded data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to calculate the total data download and upload in a particular interval of time, and store it to a database so that it can be viewed later on. Thus, this particular user logged in at this time and downloaded and uploaded this much data.

I want to do this in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `PerformanceCounter` class in `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

Noting down two class that will help you achive what you want to do.

`NetworkMonitor` class

```
public class NetworkMonitor
{
    private ArrayList adapters;
    public ArrayList monitoredAdapters;

    public NetworkMonitor()
    {
        this.adapters = new ArrayList();
        this.monitoredAdapters = new ArrayList();
        EnumerateNetworkAdapters();
    }

    private void EnumerateNetworkAdapters()
    {
        PerformanceCounterCategory category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Network Interface");

        foreach (string name in category.GetInstanceNames())
        {
            if (name == "MS TCP Loopback interface")
                continue;
            NetworkAdapter adapter = new NetworkAdapter(name);
            adapter.dlCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", name);
            adapter.ulCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec", name);
            this.adapters.Add(adapter);
            adapter.init();
        }
    }

    public NetworkAdapter[] Adapters
    {
        get
        {
            return (NetworkAdapter[])this.adapters.ToArray(typeof(NetworkAdapter));
        }
    }
}
```

`NetworkAdapter` class

```
public class NetworkAdapter
{
    // Instances of this class are supposed to be created only in an NetworkMonitor.
    internal NetworkAdapter(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private long dlSpeed, ulSpeed;
    private long dlValue, ulValue;
    private long dlValueOld, ulValueOld;

    internal string name;
    internal PerformanceCounter dlCounter, ulCounter;
    internal bool Enabled;

    internal void init()
    {
        this.dlValueOld = this.dlCounter.NextSample().RawValue;
        this.ulValueOld = this.ulCounter.NextSample().RawValue;
        this.Enabled = true;
    }

    // Obtain new sample from performance counters, and refresh the values saved in dlSpeed, ulSpeed, etc.
    // This method is supposed to be called only in NetworkMonitor, one time every second.
    internal void refresh()
    {
        this.dlValue = this.dlCounter.NextSample().RawValue;
        this.ulValue = this.ulCounter.NextSample().RawValue;

        // Calculates download and upload speed.
        this.dlSpeed = this.dlValue - this.dlValueOld;
        this.ulSpeed = this.ulValue - this.ulValueOld;
        this.dlValueOld = this.dlValue;
        this.ulValueOld = this.ulValue;
    }

    // Overrides method to return the name of the adapter.
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
    // Current download speed in bytes per second.
    public long DownloadSpeed(int Interval)
    {
        return this.dlSpeed * 1000 / Interval;
    }
    // Current upload speed in bytes per second.
    public long UploadSpeed(int Interval)
    {
        return this.ulSpeed * 1000 / Interval;
    }

}
```

All you have to do is:

```
long downloadSpeed = 0;
long uploadSpeed = 0;
NetworkMonitor networkMonitor = new NetworkMonitor();

foreach (NetworkAdapter adapter in monitor.Adapters)
{
    if (adapter.Enabled)
    {
        adapter.refresh();
        downloadSpeed += adapter.DownloadSpeed(yourTimerInterval);
        uploadSpeed += adapter.UploadSpeed(yourTimerInterval);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.
Regards.

Comment: hey thnks for ur help bt its for download an dupload speed...i want it for..the amount of data downloaded lyk 30 mb or 35 mb..etc..

Comment: Run the piece of code every second, and add up where you want to keep it. `There's not definite way to get the total amount`

Comment: hey n 1 more thing..

i m making an web application dat keeps a track of the computers on a network..i.e..who is using wich pc for internet...in dis..for ny person who wants to use internet has to first login into my apllication den he/she can use internet..so i want dat..my should run every time ny browser is opend..so he/she has to first login..and he can't use internet without logging in..and wen its logged in..den the browser is opened with its home page.